# I think there is an error in the solution. Is it correct?

Tags: real-analysis

I read the solution and think there is an error in the solution.

I think $z_1$ in red boxes should be changed to m.

Am I correct? Or did I misinterpret the solution?

I think the key is that m(the lowest f value)) can't be an interior point!

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're correct to me. Either $z_1$ should be changed to $f(z_1)$ or $m$.

Comment: where is this from?

Comment: Also: "Since $f$ is a continuous function on a compact set..." No it's not! This should read, "Since $f$ restricted to $[\min(a,b),\max(a,b)]$ is a continuous function on a compact set..."

Answer (score -1):

I'm a bit confused about this solution to start with.  We are talking about f on an open set, which is certainly not compact, so there is no guarantee it will attain a max or min there; you can close the interval of course and get your max and min.  That said, I think we can do this solution better.

Let us suppose f is not monotonic on the interval (a,b).  Then it has either a minimum or a maximum inside (a,b). Call that point c. If c is the absolute max or min, whatever f maps (a,b) into, it will contain f(c) as an endpoint and cannot be open.

Suppose c is only a local max or min.  Then consider the problem on an interval (q,r) around c where c is the absolute max or min.  So as per the above paragraph whatever f maps (q,r) into it must contain f(c) as an endpoint and cannot be open.

The arguments below can be applied to (a,b) if c is an absolute max/min or (q,r) if c is a local max/min.

Turning it around, suppose the mapping of (a,b) is not open and its included endpoint is f(c).  Then f(c) must be ≤ f(a) or f(c) ≥ f(b) -- either way  f is not monotonic on (a,b).

Note that if f is indeed monotonic on (a,b), then its map of (a,b) will certainly be open, because it will be exactly (f(a), f(b)).

What you need to do to finish up is: if f is an open mapping and so maps **every** open interval into an open interval,  it has to be monotonic on  on the entire x-axis.  I suspect you have to fuss around a little to nail down that last statement. For example, you might start with (-1,1) and keep expanding to larger intervals -- no matter how large an interval you choose, f will be monotonic, so this must apply to the real line.

Comment: -1: "Let us suppose f is not monotonic on the interval (a,b). Then it has either a minimum or a maximum inside (a,b)."  This is false: e.g. start with a straight line segment and insert a small switchback in the middle.

Comment: (Also, when it speaks of the function being continuous on a compact domain, it means the restriction of $f$ to the closed interval $[a,b]$.  This is a correct argument except for the typos that the OP has pointed out.)

Comment: Could you explain this "small switchback"?

Comment: For instance suppose that $f$ is piecewise linear with slope $1$ on $[0,1]$, then with slope $-1$ on $[1,1.1]$, then with slope $1$ on $[1.1,2]$.  The function is not monotonic but both the minimum and maximum occur at the endpoints.  In fact the restriction to $(0,2)$ has neither a minimum nor a maximum.